# How to calculate input fields values and assign it to another field while removing a field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, repeat, calculated-field

I am trying to calculate the total amount of a group of repetitive fields.

This is my markup

```
<label for="name" class="p-label-required">Amount <span style="color: red"> (Numbers only)</span></label>
<input type="text" id="amount" name="amount[]" placeholder="Amount" required="required" class="form-control inputChangeVal reqF" data-js-input-type="number" /><br/>

<div class="add_another_st"></div>
<button class="btn add_another_st_btn" style="margin-bottom: 25px;">+</button>
<hr style="margin-top: 0;">
Total Amount:
<input type="text" class="totalAmount" id="updatedTotalAmount" style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 25px; border: 0;" readonly />
```

and this is my jQuery to calculate the total whenever something happens on the `amount` fields.. 
it calculates the total correctly and assign it to the `total amount` field.

```
/* calculating and updating the total amount */
    function updateTotal() {
        var price = 0;

        jQuery(".inputChangeVal").each(function() {
            var t = parseFloat(jQuery(this).val(), 10);
            price = price + t;
        });

        var total = price.toFixed(2);
        jQuery(".totalAmount").val(total);
        console.log('updateTotal Runs');
    }
    jQuery(document).on("change, keyup", ".inputChangeVal", updateTotal);
```

but I want to calculate the amount again when an amount field is removed and it does not work / update the total whenever and amount field is removed.

the code I've created for this is here in [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/riffaz/dx32dd4y/)

How can I update the total again while a field is removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the `updateTotal()` function upon sliding up of the `wrapper` element.

```
jQuery(this).parent('div').slideUp(1000, function() {
    jQuery(this).remove();
    x--;
    updateTotal(); // updating total
});
```

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dx32dd4y/1/)**

Comment: thank you for that @siam. is it possible to call the same when function when an user clicks the browser back button? because when the user goes to the next page from this page, there will be a back button.. when the user clicks on the back button there he comes back to this page again.. all the repetitive field are gone.. only the 1st field will be in this page now.. but the total amount is the previous total amount.. but I just want to show the available fields amount only..  note : in this case browser is not refreshing.. user just come back to this page from this page's action page...

Comment: You could remove the addition calculation code within the remove as well.. https://jsfiddle.net/dx32dd4y/3/

Comment: yes I already remove that in my actual page @Rick . do you have any suggestion for my 1st comment?

Comment: It's hard to say really.. I don't fully understand what issues you are having there. Do you have a session or something that stores the data across multiple pages? I probably wouldn't rely on the data being there when hitting the browser back button.. If the button is controlled by you though using javascript you could then probably just fire that `updateTotal()` function on the event of loading that particular page of the form. Like I said though, hard to say with not knowing all your issues..

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
        debugger;
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery(this).parent('div').slideUp(1000, function() {
                jQuery(this).remove();

                x--;
        /*running again calculation 0f the total amount and while removing an amount */
        var price = 0;
        jQuery(".inputChangeVal").each(function() {
                var t = parseFloat(jQuery(this).val(), 10);
                price = price + t;
        });
        var total = price.toFixed(2);
        jQuery(".totalAmount").val(total);
        console.log('updateTotal Runs while removing');
         });
});
```